# Quantifying Country Proximity and Shared Borders

Tags: curated-data, geography

I'm trying to find a code that can quantify the proximity of countries in Europe, taking into account shared borders and I am completely stumped.

So ideally, countries that share a border have a high number and then countries where you have to pass through several borders have a significantly lower score.

Is there also a code which could tell me how many borders one would have to cross to get from country A to country B?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By "borders", do you mean geographical borders?

Comment: Yes, the shared geographical borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Inspired by J.M.'s comment I will give a more compact and more functional solution here:

```
euCountries = CountryData["Europe"];

edges = Inner[
    Function[ {c, listbc}, Sort @ UndirectedEdge[ c, # ]& /@ listbc ],
    euCountries,
    Map[ CountryData[ #, "BorderingCountries" ]&, euCountries ],
    Union
];

g = Graph[ euCountries, edges, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Large ];
```

---

**Original Solution**

A quick an dirty go at this is maybe to build a graph for say Europe with an edge connecting two countries meaning that they are neighbors.

```
countriesInEurope = CountryData[ "Europe" ];
```

We then find the neighbors for each country and store them together with the country itself in a list of strings:

```
listNeighbors = (({#}~Join~CountryData[#, "BorderingCountries"]) & /@ 
countriesInEurope) /. e_Entity :> CountryData[e, "Name"];
```

We now construct the edges for the graph with taking care of duplicates, so that two countries will only be connected by a single undirected edge:

```
countryEdges[ list_ ] := With[
   {
     country = First @ list,
     neighbors = Rest @ list
   } ,
   If[ neighbors === {}, Return[Nothing] ];
   Map[ country \[UndirectedEdge] # &, neighbors ]
];

edges = Map[ countryEdges, listNeighbors ] // RightComposition[
   Flatten,
   ReplaceAll[ UndirectedEdge[ a_, b_] :> UndirectedEdge @@ Sort@{a, b}],
   DeleteDuplicates
```

];

Now we can have our graph:

```
g = Graph[ Flatten @ listNeighbors, edges, VertexLabels -> "Name" , ImageSize -> Large]
```

---

[image]

**Working With the Graph**

We see that there are two countries in between Germany and Croatia:

```
FindShortestPath[ g, "Germany", "Croatia"]
```

> {"Germany", "Austria", "Hungary", "Croatia"}

We can also have a *CountryDistance* that would give the number of borders to cross:

```
countryDistance[a_ , b_ ] := FindShortestPath[ g, a, b] // Length // # - 1 &

countryDistance[ "Germany", "Morocco" ]
```

> 3

So with a bit of work more can be done in this line...

Comment: Here's a compact version: `euCountries = CanonicalName[CountryData["Europe"]]; edges = Union[Flatten[Table[Sort[UndirectedEdge[bord, #]], {bord, CanonicalName[CountryData[#, "BorderingCountries"]]}] & /@ euCountries]]; g = Graph[euCountries, edges, ImageSize -> Large, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`

Comment: @J.M. Interestingly, one may drop `CanonicalName` completely in your version as `VertexLabels -> "Name"` takes care of it.

Comment: I know, I just preferred storing strings instead of `Entity[]` objects in the vertices.

Comment: Is there a way to make a function for the distance between two countries without using Entities and an Internet connection?